# Compare to lists and modify specific values

Tags: python

I have a list that contains 4 keys (one of the keys is another list with date and measure). The problem is that some equipments of this list contains missing dates, i.e., it could happen measurement jumps from 12:30 to 19:25, for example.

What I want to do is compare those measures with my list containing all the dates in a 5-min interval and, when it finds a date that isn't present in the list, it adds a " " or empty value to it.

Here it is my list:

```
responseRequest =

[
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-5-3-2",
      "id":"1d72ac1a-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":144.0,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103001Z",
            "6.0"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103501Z",
            "6.0"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-6-3-9",
      "id":"1f778580-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":58.5,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103001Z",
            "2.0"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103501Z",
            "2.0"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"SCB P10-CB-5-2-6",
      "id":"1d49a464-a50c-11e7-95ec-42010afa015a",
      "power":144.0,
      "measures":[
         [
            "20200322T103000Z",
            "5.98"
         ],
         [
            "20200322T103500Z",
            "5.72"
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

And here it is what I did:

```
for cb in responseRequest:
    print(set(cb['measures'][0]))     # Gets dates from measures, [1] gives you the measured value
    for timeAmpere in cb['measures']:
        dtsCB.append(timeAmpere[0])   # List with all dates in on equipment
temp3 = [x for x in set(dts) if x not in set(dtsCB)]          # dts is a list with all complete dates
```

`temp3` is getting all the different dates. Now I'd just like to run through `dtsCB` and fill it with empty values (at `cb['measures'][1]`) where there are dates that doesn't exist in it when comparing to `dts`. Maybe just doing an `append()` with time and the measurement as a key/value in a dict, but cb has no property append()...  Can someone please help me out?

Comment: So, If I have understood correctly... when two measures are NOT in a 5-minute interval of every equipment, add " " to what exactly? Could you provide an example. Take into account people are not contextualized as you might be. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Have a look into putting your data into a `pandas.DataFrame`.  This is a very powerful and flexible data structure that will help with your sorting / filling requirements.  [Here are the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: Oh thank you @S3DEV! I'm new to Python and did not know about it;
@TomásDenisReyesSánchez, I'd like to check which 5-minute intervals are missing in `dtsCB` comparing it with `dts` (that contains ALL intervals). After that, I'd like to input this 5-minute missing to `dtsCB` add " " to them. Don't know if this is possible

Comment: Guys, I just discovered why this was not working: for some reason one of the lists had seconds like "01" or "12" in the time and, the other one, were all 00s. I cut the seconds off and I think now it's detecting which dates are not present in `dtsCB`. I only need now to create those missing dates inside `cb['measures']` and add it a " " value to it. Is this possible?